# Can Ansible roles include Python code for example a helper method?

Tags: ansible

I want to add a helper method to my Ansible role. The idea is to call this helper method for example in a task and provide a "fact" as an argument to this helper method. The helper method would return a string and a list that would be processed in the task

Comment: Are you thinking of a filter that you would use like `{{ my_fact | my_helper }}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

You can use the [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) module which allows you to run a script on remote hosts. You then use [registers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) to process your result.
Just make sure your script is inside your role path in the [files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure) subfolder.

For instance:

```
- name: run python script
  script: "script.py --argument {{argument}}"
  register: output
```

Another option would be to develop you own [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins), as Zeitounator mentioned in the comments. This would allow you to use Jinja2 template expressions to invoke your script. In this case make sure the filter is inside the filter_plugins subdirectory in your role path (worth noting is that including a custom filter in a role will also make it available in the calling playbook).

For instance:

```
- module:
    module_argument: "{{ argument | custom_filter}}"
```